# Date Mask in textbox in windows phone 7.5 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In windows phone 7.5 there is no date control ,I want to use date mask in text box and also validate  false if user input wrong date .
Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what control are you trying to hold / display the date in..? can you show some code.. there are several ways you can do this in regards to having the date displayed..

Comment: thanks ,there is normal windows phone textbox control

Comment: I posted an answer along with a link that has a full example checkout the answer this should work for you.. it's pretty straight forward

Comment: In order to post and or help you to generate some validation code, you could see if windows 7.5 supports the TryParse method when passing a valid or invalid date.

Comment: not a problem hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTimePicker](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization), so user will be able to select only valid date.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a DateTime variable like this

```
DateTime myValue = DateTime.Now;
myTextBlock.Text = myValue.ToString();
```

from here you could format it to the following if you like

Now what if you wanted to display only the Date and exclude the time? Luckily there are a number of methods available in the DateTime class which will enable you to display the date and/or time in a specific format. Let’s have a look at these methods and the output they generate.

1. myTextBlock.Text = myValue.ToShortDateString();

This statement displays only the Date in a short date format,i.e., dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy depending upon phone’s regional date time settings. E.g. 03/01/2012

1. myTextBlock.Text = myValue.ToShortTimeString();

In this statement we use the ToShortTimeString() method to display only the time. E.g. 1:06 PM

1. myTextBlock.Text = myValue.ToLongDateString();

In this statement the ToLongDateString() method displays the Day of the week followed by the Date in numbers, the Month in alphabets and the year in numbers. E.g. Thursday, March 01, 2012.

use this link as a reference 
[Working with DateTime Windows Phone 7.5](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/working-datetime-windows-phone-75-mango-apps-development-part-10)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.95).aspx

Try use TryParse method to know if string written to textbox can be converted to DateTime, if true then its valid.